# How to correctly inject a factory using Jasmine / karma and test it?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my factory / `base.js`:

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])

    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
```

And this is my `test_base.js`:

```
describe('Factory: BaseService', function() {
    var fctry, mockBackend;

    beforeEach(function() {

        module('BaseApp');

        inject(function($factory, $httpBackend) {
            mockBackend = $httpBackend;
            fctry = $factory('BaseService', {});
        });
    });

    it('logout() should POST to /logout', function() {
        // I want to test if the logout(cb) function posts to /logout and, on success, redirect to '/'
        // but on failure, calls accessErrors and the cb.
    });
});
```

This is my karma config file:

```
files: [
  '../angular.js',
  'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

  '../base.js',

  'tests/test_base.js',
],
```

When I do `karma start` and run the tests, I get this error / fail:

```
Chromium 48.0.2564 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) Factory: BaseService logout() should POST to /logout FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $factoryProvider <- $factory
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24factoryProvider%20%3C-%20%24factory

...

Chromium 48.0.2564 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.053 secChromium 48.0.2564 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.114 secs / 0.053 secs)
```

How come it is failing already and how come it is saying that `$factoryProvider` is an unknown provider?

Comment: just inject your service BaseService and mock the method you need.

Comment: @sdfacre Hm, what exactly would be the benefit in mocking the method I need? Wouldn't injecting BaseService and the methods by calling `BaseService.methodName` work in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It thinks you're trying inject **factory**, which is a function, not a provider, so that won't work.

You're also missing out on the [underscore trick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject#resolving-references-underscore-wrapping-)

Try changing this:

```
var fctry, mockBackend;
beforeEach(function() {

    module('BaseApp');

    inject(function($factory, $httpBackend) {
        mockBackend = $httpBackend;
        fctry = $factory('BaseService', {});
    });
});
```

To this:

```
var BaseService, $httpBackend;
beforeEach(function() {

    module('BaseApp');

    inject(function(_BaseService_, _$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        BaseService = _BaseService_;
    });
});
```